# Sorcery User signup error, Invalid attribute password_confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep getting error saying Invalid attribute password_confirmation. I cant figure out what i am doing wrong. Can anyone explain what the secure parameters that needs to be passed in sorcery User controller to create a user?

**Error I keep getting**

```
Failures:

  1) Users can sign Up With Valid attributes
     Failure/Error: @user = User.new(user_params)

     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute 'password_confirmation' for User.
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `create'
     # ./spec/feature/sign_up_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # NoMethodError:
     #   undefined method `password_confirmation=' for #<User:0x00563958734578>
     #   ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

**My Controller**

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController 

layout 'static_application' 

   def new
      @user = User.new  
   end

   def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
         flash[:notice] = 'Thank you for Applying for PetroHub account. We are currently reviewing your application, which might take upto 24hrs.'
         redirect_to user_thankyou_path(@user)
      else
         flash[:alert] = 'Oops! something went wrong. Please check your application and resubmit. Thank you.'
       end   
    end

      def thank_you
        @user = User.find(params[:id])   
      end

      private

      def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name,:last_name,:business_name,:phone_number,:cell_number,:street_address,:apt_suite,:city,:state,:zip_code,:tax_id,:ssn,:in_biz,:terms,:email,:password,:password_confirmation)
    end 
  end
```

**My Spec**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature 'Users can sign Up' do
  scenario 'With Valid attributes' do
    visit '/'
    click_link 'apply'

    expect(page.current_url).to eq signup_url

    fill_in 'First Name', with: 'John'
    fill_in 'Last Name', with: 'Doe'
    fill_in 'Business Name', with: 'Acme Inc'
    fill_in 'Phone Number', with: '2124567890'
    fill_in 'Cell Number', with: '5202124567'
    fill_in 'Street Address', with: '212 Wise St'
    fill_in 'Apt/Suite', with: '410'
    fill_in 'City', with: 'New york'
    select "New York", :from => "State"
    fill_in 'Zip Code', with: '11104'
    fill_in 'Tax ID', with: '12345678'
    fill_in 'SSN', with: '124000987'
    fill_in 'How many years in Business?', with: '5'
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'test@example.com'
    fill_in 'user_password', with: 'password'
    fill_in 'user_password_confirmation', with: 'password'
    check('user_terms')
    click_button 'Apply'


    expect(page).to have_content 'Thank you for Applying for PetroHub account. We are currently reviewing your application, which might take upto 24hrs.'
  end

  scenario 'With Invalid attributes' do
  end
end
```

Comment: I haven't used Sorcery but I think you model may be missing `validates_confirmation_of :password`. That creates an accessor on the model for `password_confirmation`. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_confirmation_of

Comment: AWESOME! That was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `validates_confirmation_of :password` to your model. That will create an attribute in the model object.

However, note that this makes all editing of the model object's password require a confirmation, including in the Rails console. It's best to enforce the confirmation in your controller or in a service object.